# SQL Server - Get all rows of products e accessories checkin tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two tables as follow:

**Table ProductsCheckin**

```
ProductCheckinID | ProductName | Status

1                | Machine 1   | Returned
2                | Machine 2   | Not Returned
3                | Machine 3   | Returned
```

**Table AccessoriesCheckin**

```
AccessoriesCheckinID | ProductCheckinID | ProductName          | Status       


1                    | 2                | Accessory1_Machine_2 | Returned
2                    | 2                | Accessory2_Machine_2 | Returned
3                    | 3                | Accessory1_Machine_3 | Not Returned
```

Is it possible to make a query to return the following result?

```
ProductCheckinID | ProductName          | Status

1                | Machine 1            | Returned
2                | Machine 2            | Not Returned
2                | Accessory1_Machine_2 | Returned
2                | Accessory2_Machine_2 | Returned
3                | Machine 3            | Returned
3                | Accessory1_Machine_3 | Not Returned
```

Sorry if this basic question has already been asked and answered and my Googling skills failed, but I am having really difficult to find the solution.

Obs: I am using **SQL Server 2014**.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far???  You said this is a basic question, but have you even attempted this basic question?  If you have, where's the query?  If you haven't, then try it and post your query.

Comment: @Eric, I have tried a lot of type of joins to resolve that but unfortunately, without success. I am not a SQL expert like you guy, anyway sorry if my post wasn't completely detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for `union all`

```
select ProductCheckinID, ProductName, Status from  ProductsCheckin
union all
select ProductCheckinID, ProductName, Status from AccessoriesCheckin
```

Here's [Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/IZGZB43630)

Output

```
ProductCheckinID    ProductName             Status
--------------------------------------------------
1                   Machine 1               Returned
2                   Machine 2               Not Returned
3                   Machine 3               Returned
2                   Accessory1_Machine_2    Returned
2                   Accessory2_Machine_2    Returned
3                   Accessory1_Machine_3    Not Returned
```

Comment: Hi uzi tks for the reply, the problem in this query it is not returning the ProductName and the Status from the both tables, only from the ProductsCheckin.

Comment: @VitorMoscolini, added rextester demo and output. Can you show where's the difference? I do not see any difference. Just order is different

Comment: you are right it worked. I didn't realize that it was not ordered. Sorry for the confusion and many thanks for your help.